# core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Table -> FilterService]:

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to use PrimeNg Table control in my application - a beginner in PrimeNg & Angular as well
and am getting an error `No provider for FilterService!` as below

> core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Table -> FilterService]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Table -> FilterService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for FilterService! NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Table ->
> FilterService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Table ->
> FilterService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for FilterService!
> at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
> (core.js:725)
> at resolveToken (core.js:11918)
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:11862)
> at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
> (core.js:11764)
> at resolveToken (core.js:11918)
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:11862)
> at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
> (core.js:11764)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:20234)
> at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
> (core.js:20905)
> at resolveDep (core.js:21276)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
> at zone.js:913
> at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
> (zone.js:423)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
> at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
> (zone.js:422)
> at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
> at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
> at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
> [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
> at invokeTask (zone.js:1693)

What I have done

1. I have installed PrimeNg as given in the PrimeNg Getting Started set up .
2. After that I have added  the below in `app.module.ts`

> import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
>
> ```
> import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
>
> imports:[
>  ...
>  ButtonModule,
>     TableModule]
> ```

3. If I use Button I am not getting any issue `<button pButton type="button" label="Click" ></button>`
4. But if I place p-table I am getting the above mentioned error.

(pTable like ==> <p-table [value]="cars"> .....

Comment: It should work as per your changes. Try to add import { FilterService } from 'primeng/api'; and add FilterService in to your module providers array. Still not work then please provide your code to check more.

Comment: wow works like a charm, the error has gone. Thanks a lot, I've been trying for many hours now
Please add it as answer so that i can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as per your changes. Error is saying filter service is not provided in module providers array.

Try to add **import { FilterService } from 'primeng/api';** and add FilterService in to your module providers array.